# Let anonymus users create events in my own personnal google agenda through api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

---

Hi everyone,

Like it is written in the title, I'm trying to build something like Calendly app : giving my react website users the ability to create an event in my own personnal google agenda.

To reach this goal, I've red a lot of documentation and here is what I found :

- I need to build a classic OAuth process and ask users permissions through consent screen (what I absolutely don't need because they gonna give me their infos such as email or name earlier in the form).
- I need to call the api through a service account which is ask for a Workspace paying account (and really too huge in terms of features, compared to the needs I have).

Does anyone can tell me if there is an other solution to my problem, that I have not discover yet ? Or, I'm gonna need to get through classic OAuth process, to avoid spamming ?

Thank you very much.
Sourouche.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to build a classic OAuth process and ask users permissions through consent screen (what I absolutely don't need because they gonna give me their infos such as email or name earlier in the form).

If you want to allow them to write to your Calendar then you need to grant them access to your calendar you only need them to grant access to their own calendars.

> I need to call the api through a service account which is ask for a Workspace paying account (and really too huge in terms of features, compared to the needs I have).

its true that service account only work with google workspace accounts.

## recommendation.

Create an Oauth2 system authorize your application once to your own account and store the refresh token every time someone wants to write to your calendar you can use the refresh token to get a new access token and write to your own account that way.

Main issue will be that you will need to verify this application as refresh tokens will only last for a week until your app is set to production and has been verified.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @DaImTo. Let's make things clear : Do you mean that I'm gonna need to get through the consent screen only once, just to authorize **my** fontend app to write to **my** agenda ? And then, I'm gonna only need to ask for refreshToken, everytime someone will try to create a new event ?